# Is it possible to include js files from static resources into listview onclick JS button?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, force.com, custom-button, static-resources

Is it possible to include js files from static resources into listview onclick JS button? REQUIRESCRIPT can't be used anymore for static resources because of this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XRLAA2) that won't be fixed. The only possible idea for now is to host those files outside of Salesforce and reference them using REQUIRESCRIPT function then.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is first save the code as a separate JS file then create a new static resource in your Salesforce Org and add the JS File into the resource.Now to include the javascript code in your vf page just add this line(say your static resource is named as test)

```
apex:includeScript value="{! $Resource.test}"
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don't think this is what he was asking. He's talking about a list view button not a VF page

Comment: correct, it's not about VF page which is the obvious scenario